# After upgrading a project: NSTableVIew doesn't update correctly after deleting an existing row

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode5

I've weird issue with a `NSTableView`, since when I've upgraded my project to `xCode5` from `xCode3`.

If I add a new row, the view is correctly updated and the new line is shown. However, if I delete an existing row, the tableview is not updated and I need to close and reopen the window to see the updated list of items.

The `NSTableView` and the `NSArrayController`, used as datasource, are both included in a xib file. To add and remove the rows, I act on the array controller, by adding and removing objects. This is the code to remove the item:

```
[[[self creatorsArrayController] selectedObjects] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(remove)];
[[self creatorsArrayController] remove:sender];
```

Apparently the old programmer was using both methods for some reason. I've also tried to remove one of the two lines, but nothing changes.

The code worked perfectly in previous versions of xCode, I suspect something might have been changed after the upgrade in the xib file, but I can't what it is.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the tableView, use

[yourTableViewOutletName reloadData];

AFTER a row is removed.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried, but it doesn't work. What it is strange to me, is that the table is updated correctly for any other operation, but not for removing a row.

Answer (score 0):

The first of the two lines you're using doesn't make much sense to me (but I can't really know, because in that line the `remove` message is being sent to the objects being removed, maybe that's important in your application), anyway it doesn't seem to be related to the removal of the object from the Array.

You're giving little information, so it's hard to tell for sure, but here are a couple of thinks to check:

1. The second line should work only with the selected objects. If you want to programmatically delete objects that are not selected this method doesn't work (you should use `removeObject` or `removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndex:` for example).
2. If you're using Core Data, you might consider taking a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArrayController/removeObject%3a) for some notes that might be relevant.
3. Check that your 'delete' button is bound to the the NSArrayController correctly (unless you're deleting manually)

Comment: Yes, I select the item before to remove it, and I'm deleting manually (as you can see from the code above). I would like to underline that everything was working before the upgrade to xCode5, and that the problem is about refreshing the table (the object is correctly removed from the arrayController).